# Calculating opposite partition in median of two sorted lists

Tags: python, algorithm

From: https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/description/

> There are two sorted arrays nums1 and nums2 of size m and n
>   respectively.
>
> Find the median of the two sorted arrays. The overall run time
>   complexity should be O(log (m+n)).
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> nums1 = [1, 3]
> nums2 = [2]
> ```
>
> The median is 2.0
>
> ```
> Example 2:
> nums1 = [1, 2]
> nums2 = [3, 4]
> ```
>
> The median is (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5

I have the following solution (based off of this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPFhl65R7ww):

```
class Solution:
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, x, y):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :rtype: float
        """
        x, y = (x, y) if len(x) <= len(y) else (y, x)
        total_len_even = (len(x) + len(y)) % 2 == 0
        left, right = 0, len(x)
        while left <= right:
            partition_x = (left + right) // 2
            # not sure why we add 1 below...
            half_el_count = (len(x) + len(y) + 1) // 2
            partition_y = half_el_count - partition_x 

            max_left_x = float('-inf') if partition_x == 0 else x[partition_x - 1]
            min_right_x = float('inf') if partition_x == len(x) else x[partition_x]

            max_left_y = float('-inf') if partition_y == 0 else y[partition_y - 1]
            min_right_y = float('inf') if partition_y == len(y) else y[partition_y]

            if max_left_x <= min_right_y and max_left_y <= min_right_x:
                return (max(max_left_x, max_left_y) + min(min_right_x, min_right_y)) / 2.0 if total_len_even else float(max(max_left_x, max_left_y))
            elif max_left_x > min_right_y:
                right = partition_x - 1
            else:
                left = partition_x + 1
```

where `partition_x` and `partition_y` means all elements before this partition index are less than or equal to the overall median.

My question revolves around this line:
`half_el_count = (len(x) + len(y) + 1) // 2`
The idea is that we want to find partition y such that, if you take the total number of elements in the combined list, the number of elements before partition x + number of elements before partition y are half the total number of elements (since we are, after all, trying to find the median).

However, shouldn't the half_el_count then be: `(len(x) + len(y)) // 2`? In the video, he mentions adding 1 makes it easier to handle even or odd cases, but I'm not sure what this means.

The Leetcode solution as well just says:
`i+j=m−i+n−j (or: m - i + n - j + 1m−i+n−j+1)` without specifying why the extra 1 is added. Can someone explain why we add the extra 1?

Comment: I think this could be solved with a kind of "nested" binary search. Take the median of X (O(1)), find the position of that element in Y using binary search (O(logm)); you now know the number of elements in both X and Y smaller/greater then the median. You can now correct the median accordingly using binary search in X, e.g. trying again with the median of the lower partition, calculate it's position in Y again, and so on. So you binary search the median in X, using binary search in Y to determine whether to go low or high. Overall complexity would be O(logn*logm), unless I'm mistaken, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution(object):
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
        a=nums1+nums2
        a.sort()
        n=len(a)
        if len(a)==0 or len(a)==1:
            return a[0]
        if n%2!=0:
            s=(n/2)
            return a[s]
        else:
            return (a[n/2]+a[(n/2)-1])/2.0
```

I tested this on the leetcode link you provided this passes without any runtime error. Hope this helps

Comment: "The overall run time complexity should be O(log (m+n))."